# Bug or misuse : docker layer content not available in final image

Tags: docker

I am having a hard time trying to build a docker image for some python project, but at some point a `RUN` command resulting content is not available in the next `RUN`.

I mean I have a `RUN` command that generate a directory with some content and that directory is not available for the next `RUN` command.

Here is the `Dockerfile` snippet :

```
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true && \
    poetry install -n --no-root --no-dev && \
    ls -la
RUN ls -la
```

The first `ls -la` shows a `.venv` directory (see below) while it is not present anymore in the second one.

And here is the build output:

```
Step 9/14 : RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true &&     poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true &&     poetry install -n --no-root --no-dev &&     ls -la
 ---> Running in 3a93a4994133
      ...
drwxrwxr-x 4 root odoo  4096 Sep 29 20:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Sep 16 02:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 odoo odoo  4096 Sep 29 20:08 .venv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 odoo odoo 15824 Sep  2 23:18 poetry.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 odoo odoo  2057 Sep  2 23:50 pyproject.toml
drwxr-xr-x 3 odoo odoo  4096 Sep 29 20:08 src
Removing intermediate container 3a93a4994133
 ---> 694c4e54863c
Step 10/14 : RUN ls -la
 ---> Running in 5d0ebcf8f1e9
total 32
drwxrwxr-x 3 root odoo  4096 Sep 29 20:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Sep 16 02:35 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 odoo odoo 15824 Sep  2 23:18 poetry.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 odoo odoo  2057 Sep  2 23:50 pyproject.toml
drwxr-xr-x 3 odoo odoo  4096 Sep 29 20:08 src
Removing intermediate container 5d0ebcf8f1e9
 ---> 750255eac6bb
```

If someone can provide any lead, it would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Note : After the build, when I run the container, the `.venv` folder is not present.
If I run the `poetry install -n --no-root --no-dev` from inside the container, everything is installed correcty and my `.venv` folder becomes available.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What's before this in the Dockerfile?  (One thing that comes to mind is the Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive, though it's a little unusual to use it.)